# How can I store a pair of numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, std-pair

I'm trying to learn C++ and right now I'm writing a program that needs to output a list of pairs of integers.

What is the best way to handle this?  I don't have the boost library available on our linux computers at school, so I don't believe I can use boost::tuple.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have a sufficiently recent version of g++ that has tr1 support, `boost::tuple` is included as `std::tr1::tuple`; as others note in answers below, though, you can just use `std::pair` for pairs.

Answer (score 31):

Have a look at [`std::pair<object, object>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)

EDIT:

It's standard C++ and part of what is known as the STL (Standard Template Library). It's a collection of nice data structures that are generic (i.e. may be used to store any C++ object type). This particular structure is used to store a "tuple" or a pair of numbers together. It's basically an object with members "first" and "second" that refer to the first and second objects (of any type!) that you store in them.

So just declare an array of `pair<int, int>`, or better yet, use another STL type called the "vector" to make a dynamically-sized list of `pair<int, int>`: `vector<pair<int, int> > myList`.

Hey what do you know! A dynamically-sized list of pairs already exists and it's called a map! Using it is as simple as `#include <map>` and declaring a `map<int, int> myMap`!!!

EDIT:

Yes, as pointed out, a map well "maps" one object to another, so you cannot have repeated lefthand-side values. If that's fine then a map is what you're looking for, otherwise stick to the vector of pair.... or take a look at multimaps.

[`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)

Comment: Note that outputting the pair will not be handled by `cout` (as it is for `int` or `double`) -- you will have to handle it separately.

Comment: In C++98 and C++03, you must use `vector<pair<int, int> >` (notice the space at the end!) because `>>` parses as "right shift".  This will be fixed in C++0x.

Comment: @ephemient Interesting... I bet that generates a very helpful compiler error. ;)

Comment: -1 because map isn't the same as treating pairs of values. Map does what it name says: maps one Key-value to another value. So, if using map, you can't have repetitions of the left-value.

Comment: @Bruno Yes you can - std::multimap

Comment: Neither `std::map` nor `std::multimap` are "a list of pairs".  Lists retain their order, map collections do not.

Answer (score 19):

Use std::pair?

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::pair <int, int> p = std::make_pair( 1, 2 );
    std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << std::endl;
}
```

You can make a vector of pairs:

```
typedef std::pair <int, int> IntPair;

...

std::vector <IntPair> pairs;
pairs.push_back( std::make_pair( 1, 2 ) );
pairs.push_back( std::make_pair( 3, 4 ) );
```

Comment: Would you suggest std::pair over map?

Comment: Mithrax, map is just a wrapper around pair. It uses the pair code internally.

Comment: @Mithrax That depends what you want to do with the pairs. If one is a key and one is a value, then you should use std::map, which is in fact implemented using std::pair.

Comment: @Computer Guru map is not "just a wrapper" around pair. If anything it is a wrapper around  a red-black balanced binary tree.

Comment: Sure. Versus a vector<pair> which would be an array list wrapper of pair.

Point is, at the end of the day, you can't suggest pair instead of map because they're apples and oranges. One of them is a basic datastructure that represents a tuple, the other USES the tuple to make an even larger structure :)

Keep in mind the OP is a beginner to C++

Comment: Nice answer, I just want to add that in `C++11`, creating vector of pairs is really easy: `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pairs = {{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}};`

Answer (score 9):

While std::pair is the best approach to use, I'm surprised nobody mentioned pre-stl solution:

```
struct Pair {
    int first;
    int second;
};
```

It is worrying that people think that they need boost for such a trivial problem.

Comment: Pre-STL like in pre-standard, previous millennium? And you wonder why nobody mentioned it? Additionally, your code lacks several important/nice features of `std::pair` so it doesn’t even serve for illustration purpose. In fact, what’s the purpose of mentioning this method at all?

Comment: Konrad, I did say that std::pair is better.
I don't see why my code doesn't serve for illustration purpose.
My main point was that sometimes people forget about simple solutions.

Comment: If you're just trying to learn C++, this is easily the best answer presented. It's simple, uncomplicated and easy to adapt to other problems. Once they get used to struct, adapting to class and providing methods for things like MyObject.SecondValue is easy to teach. Combined with the array suggestion above (ie Pair[] MyValues) there's really no reason not to accept this answer.

Comment: I absolutely agree with nathanchere, for teaching purposes this is easily the best answer.  Regardless of whether production code would define a new type when std::pair already exists, someone first learning C++ should be introduced to how it is done.

Comment: Pardon my potential ignorance; *where* is it stated that `pair` has anything to do with the Boost? I'm referring to this: `It is worrying that people think that they need boost for such a trivial problem.` STL != Boost?